# Django: Offer has many Products

Tags: python, django

How to make a relation in Django that Offer model has Products and Products beyond to the one Offer.

```py
    from django.db import models

    class Offer(models.Model):

        city = models.CharField(
          max_length=100)

        street = models.CharField(
          max_length=100)

        offer_taken = models.BooleanField(
          default=False)

        products = # models.OneToManyField(Product) ??

    class Product(models.Model):
        product_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The documentation has details. [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships)

Comment: But when I share Product form I want there have oppurtunity to create products but I have not that option right now

Comment: Simply, when I have in form city, street I want have oppurtunity to add products in the same form

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. But try using [Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)